# Browser detection in a Eclipse RAP application

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser, browser-detection, eclipse-rap

I was wondering if it is possible to detect the browser (especially IE) in a Eclipse RAP application. I'd like to inform the server about what browser the client is using, so that it can show adapted views.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like I asked the question too early. The solution is:

```
    String answer = RWT.getRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");
    boolean forInternetExplorer = (answer != null && answer.indexOf("MSIE") != -1);
```